# Preencher DropDown a partir da seleção de outro DropDown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html5, json

Galera, estou tentando preencher um `DropDown` a partir da seleção de outro `DropDown`, basicamente, quando o usuário selecionar um estado em um `DropDown`, as cidades deste estado devem ser exibidas em outro `DropDown`, dinamicamente.

Tenho o seguinte código:

**VIEW**

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            Departamento:
        </label>
        <div id="EstadoDifBrasil">                                
            @this.AutoSelect(x => x.StatePar).Class("form-control required").FirstOption("", "Selecione uma opção")                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            Cidade:
        </label>
        <div id="CidadeDifBrasil">
            @this.AutoSelect(x => x.CityPar).Class("form-control required").FirstOption("", "Selecione uma opção")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#StatePar").change(function () {
    var idStatePar = $("#StatePar").val();
    $.post("@Url.Action(MVC.Escritorio.Clientes.VerificarCidadeDifBr())", { codCitySel: idStatePar })
        .success(function (result) {
            alert(result.length);
        })
        .error(function (ex) {
            alert('Erro ' + ex);
        })
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual JsonResult VerificarCidadeDifBr(int codCitySel)
{
    var xpto = new List<TCity>();
    xpto = TCity.ListAllCities().Where(x => x.State.Id == codCitySel).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList(); //.ToSelectList(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

    return Json(xpto, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

No `controller` eu consigo listar as cidades do estado que seleciono, mas não consigo fazer retornar para a view via `Json`, apenas da o `alert "Erro: [object Object]"`.

Alguém tem alguma luz, por favor?

Obrigado e ótima semana!

Comment: Seu método é get e você tá usando $.post, tentou mudar pra get?

Comment: @FilipeOliveira, tentei mudar, tanto ambos para GET como para POST e o problema persiste o mesmo =/. Obrigadão!

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o $.ajax ? Você também pode verificar o erro pelo console do Chrome, caso haja erro de script ou até mesmo verificar qual foi o retorno da Request através da aba "Network" do Chrome(F12). Sendo assim você terá certeza sobre o que foi retornado de erro do servidor, se houve algum erro. Além disso se passar essa funcion em "error", você terá mais detalhes: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você complicou muito. Você poderia ter escrito o evento Ajax assim:

```
@section Scripts 
{
    <script>
        $("#StatePar").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Departamentos/CidadesPorDepartamento/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#CityPar").empty();
                    $("#CityPar").append('<option value>Selecione...</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                        $("#CityPar").append('<option value="' + element.CityId + '">' + element.Name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

*Action* em *Controller*:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual JsonResult CidadesPorDepartamento(int id)
{
    var xpto = TCity.ListAllCities()
                    .Where(x => x.State.Id == codCitySel)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                    .Select(x => new { CityId = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
                    .ToList(); //.ToSelectList(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

    return Json(xpto, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```